# How to return specific field's value in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

how can I return a specific value for a specific document in MongoDB? For example, I have a schema that looks like:

```
{
"_id" : "XfCZSje7GjynvMZu7",
"createdAt" : ISODate("2015-03-23T14:52:44.084Z"),
"services" : {
    "password" : {
        "bcrypt" : "$2a$10$tcb01VbDMVhH03mbRdKYL.79FPj/fFMP62BDpcvpoTfF3LPgjHJoq"
    },
    "resume" : {
        "loginTokens" : [ ]
    }
},
"emails" : {
    "address" : "abc123@gmu.edu",
    "verified" : true
},
"profile" : {
    "companyName" : "comp1",
    "flagged" : true,
    "phoneNum" : "7778883333"
}}
```

I want to return and store the value for profile.flagged specifically for the document with `_id : XfCZSje7GjynvMZu7`. So far I have tried:

```
db.users.find({_id:'myfi3E4YTf9z6tdgS'},{admin:1})
```

and

```
db.users.find({_id: 'myfi3E4YTf9z6tdgS'}, {profile:admin});
```

I want the query to return `true` or `false` depending on the assigned value.

Can someone help? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, something like that. I want it to return "true" or "false" depending on the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB queries always return document objects, not single values.  So one way to do this is with shell code like:

```js
var flagged =
   db.users.findOne({_id: 'myfi3E4YTf9z6tdgS'}, {'profile.flagged': 1}).profile.flagged;
```

Note the use of `findOne` instead of `find` so that you're working with just a single doc instead of the cursor that you get with `find`.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer here is the method `.distinct()` [(link here)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)

Use it like this:

```
db.users.find({_id:'myfi3E4YTf9z6tdgS'},{admin:1}).distinct('admin')
```

The result will be: `1` or `0`